# Why does my lighting not work Blender v.28

Tags: shaders, lighting

I am new to blender and I am following along with a youtube tutorial. I have tried to add lights but none have any effect on the object I have made, like the icon and direction shows but the literal lighting is not there. All objects have designated materials and I have messed with the strength and radius etc... but still nothing. I'm hoping it's a simple fix but I am not sure what's happening.
link to file here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/42qxlq2omy9wq37/Sheeps.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest issue is that the light you are using was only 10W. This is the default "power" of new lights added to the scene with the exception of a sun which starts at a value of 1. This is why all the new lights you added seemed to have no effect - they were way too dim. I upped it to 10000W and the light shines brightly. Also, however, you have the spot radius size set to 126 - I think something like 65 should be OK for what you're doing, unless you have some special need for it. Click the "show cone" box to make the light cone cast by the spotlight more visible so you can see where it's going. See below:

[image: LightCone]